# How to cut some chars from string?

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell, cut

```
echo "(2abcd3rr3)" |
```

I want my final output to be: `2abcd3rr3`

Comment: Pretty harsh: downvotes and closevotes with no comments. C'mon people, manners.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `tr` command:

```
echo "(2abcd3rr3)" | tr -d "()"
```

Answer (score 1):

For those simple string operation, you don't need spend a new process for the powerful tools like sed/awk/grep... bash provided built-in substitution:

```
$ a="(foo123)" 
$ echo ${a//[)(]}    
foo123
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "(2abcd3rr3)" |grep -oP '\(\K[^)]+'
2abcd3rr3
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "(2abcd3rr3)" | sed $'s/[^[:alnum:]\t]//g'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

Just try below php code

```
str_replace(array( '(', ')' ), '', $coords);
```

Comment: I don't see `php` anywhere in the question's tags.